# A step back in a path hierarchy

Tags: java, path, hierarchy

I have a path to a folder and want to change it. But first I want to get a step back.

```
String path = "C:\Users\Jurgen\Java\Project\Folder\inner_folder\";
```

How do I get a step back in a path hierarchy?
For example:

```
String path = "C:\Users\Jurgen\Java\Project\Folder\";
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Extract a [substring](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#substring(int)) up until the [last slash](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#lastIndexOf(int))

```
String newPath = path.substring(0, path.lastIndexOf('\'));
```

**Edit:** (*because I'm being challenged on this answer*)

Some people will tell you that treating paths as strings is wrong, in this case it doesn't make a difference.  The other option of creating a `Path` object then using it's .`getParent()` method or prior to Java 7, a `File` object.

Comment: unexplained downvoters, *rolls eyes*

Comment: Substring operations on Paths are a seriously bad idea *rolls eyes*

Comment: You're treating a `Path` as if it were a `String`, which it isn't.

Comment: `path` in this case, is a `String`

Comment: Capitalized it. Are you happy? Just because it looks like a String and you can in many cases treat it as a `String` does not mean that it is a `String` or you should try to treat it as one. It's a bit like 123 may look like an `int`, but it's actually 3 `chars`.

Comment: It doesn't look like a `String`, it *is* a `String`.  The other answer actually requires it to be "converted" to a `Path`

Comment: Yes, the `path` variable in this case is unfortunately a `String`. The sane choice is to convert it to its proper type which is `Path`, instead of trying to treat it as a String which it isn't. It's like asking how could I divide `String number = "100";` by 10? The answer is not "by removing the last character".

Comment: Until java 1.7 there was no path, so back then it wasn't a bad idea to use it as a String

Comment: No, before Java 7 you would have converted it to a `File`.

Comment: The answer isn't "*by removing the last character*", it's by removing the first character to the left of the decimal point (which is actually quicker than a cast then a division, depending on your needs) and this is nothing like editing the `String` representation of a path.  A REST URI is more of a comparison and it's common to do it this way with URIs...because they represent directory structures.  Just because there is now an object to do the work for us, doesn't mean it's wrong to do it by hand.

Comment: Well, both answers would be a solution. Thanks for that. I have liked both. But this one is more helpfull in my case.

Comment: I've edited it to include your recommendations, people.

Comment: I'm not challenging you because of me being an annoying b..person. See [here](http://thedailywtf.com/articles/shadow-over-xml) for a heartwarning example what happens when people treat things as `Strings` just because to an uneducated observer it looks like a `String`.

Comment: Never said you were.  This is a pretty simple case though.  Also, did you post the wrong link?

Answer (score 1):

Convert it to a `Path` with `Paths.get(path);` and use its `getParent()` method.

Comment: Ah thanks, wasn't sure if it would handle it.

Comment: so if i want to go a view steps back, i can just use the "getParent" method several times?